# Struggling to setup VSCode to compile c++17 or higher on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang, c++17

I am learning new feature of C++, updated in version C++ 17 and higher. I have setup my VSCode to for C++ programming using Microsoft's C/C++ compiler extension and also updated the Xcode for my clang update.
Source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector <int> myints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    for(int i : myints){
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // partition method from STL :
    partition(myints.begin(), myints.end(), [](auto x){return xx%2 ==0;});

    for(int i : myints){
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But while compiling it still giving me an error like,
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how to update clang for C++ 17 or higher.
Or some other extension which solve my problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you extracted (and added to your question) the compile command issued by your IDE.  You probably don't need to update your compiler; your error messages suggest that it hasn't been told to *use* modern C++ extensions (and suggest a flag to turn them on).

Comment: Have you tried using `-std=C++17`? What happened?

Comment: --std=C++17 works fine. But if anyone is still having any issues while compiling you can use vsCode extension called "Code Runner" by Jun Han. It will directly run code with latest compiler available.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please attach your main src code.

Second you can't initialize a vector in a data field. You need to do it in a constructor using member initializer lists:

```
MyClass(): myints{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But as per my knowledge initializing a vector directly like an array is completely valid.

Comment: Try this then:
Use g++ -std=c++11 <filename> when compiling.